# For the recent Eventbrite API, what is the API call for event searching?

Tags: android, api, eventbrite

I am trying to make an API call to Eventbrite platform in searching for nearby events with a query search term.

For example, I want to search for public events with the term or tag, '**apple**', in **San Diego, California**.

How would I go in approaching this manner via API call?

I am aware that this documentation shows a deprecated version of it:
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event-search
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/changelog

But there is no concise answer to my issue.

Any help is appreciated.